# Pass parameters from powershell to stored procedure

Tags: sql, powershell

I was trying to pass 2 parameters to my stored procedure using powershell.

My code is as below, when I run it in powershell there's no error. However, it doesn't seem the parameters has been passed, because I can't get the correct result. Is there anything wrong on below?

```
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=AMSDataWarehouse    Test;Integrated Security=SSPI"
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$sqlcmd.CommandText = "YQBReport1"
$param1=$sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@from" , [System.Data.SqlDbType]::DateTime)
$param1.Value = "2013-03-13"
$param2=$sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@to" , [System.Data.SqlDbType]::DateTime)
$param2.Value = "2013-03-14"
$SqlConnection.Open()
$sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$SqlConnection.Close()
$SQLResult =$DataSet.Tables[0]
$commands = $SQLResult | foreach-object -process { $_.output }> output.ps1
.\output.ps1
```

Adding code of YQBReport1

```
create PROCEDURE YQBreport1 
AS 
declare @from datetime, @to datetime, @TypeBigAC char(3)
select @TypeBigAC='333'

Select 
'$application = New-Object -ComObject Visio.Application;
$documents = $application.Documents;
$document = $documents.Add("AMSGantt.vst");
$pages = $application.ActiveDocument.Pages;
$page = $pages.Item(1);
$shape500 = $page.DrawLine(2,7.9,11,7.9);
$shape500.TextStyle = "Title";
$shape500.LineStyle = "Title";'
as output
union all

select
'$shape500.text = '+'"'+'Assignation de Barrières-' +      DATENAME(WEEKDAY,@from)+','+DATENAME(MONTH,@from)+'   '+DATENAME(DAY,@from)+','+DATENAME(YEAR,@from)+'"'+';'
as output
Union all

SELECT 
'$shape'+cast(ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) as varchar)+' =     $page.DrawRectangle'+'('+CAST(X1 as varchar)+','+CAST(Y1 as varchar)+','+CAST(X2 as   varchar)+','+CAST(Y2 as varchar)+')'+';'
+'$shape'+ cast(ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) as varchar)+'.'+'LineStyle =    Gantt"'+';'
+'$shape'+ cast(ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) as varchar)+'.'+'TextStyle =      "Gantt"'+case when left(arrival, 2)='AC' THEN 'Red' ELSE '' END+ CASE WHEN LEFT(Departure,      2)='AC' THEN 'Red' ELSE '' END+';'
    +'$shape'+ cast(ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) as varchar)+'.FillStyle =        "Gantt'+CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(@TypeBigAC, [ACType Iata])<>0 THEN ' Big AC' ELSE ''        END+'"'+';'
+'$shape'+ cast(ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) as varchar)+'.Text = "'+case when    LEN(arrival)<>0 THEN Arrival ELSE '###' END +' / '+ case when len([ACType Iata])<>0 then    [ACType Iata] else ' ' end +' / '+ CASE WHEN LEN(Departure)<>0 THEN Departure ELSE '###'    END +'"'+';'
+'$shape'+ cast(100+ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) as varchar)+' =   $page.DrawLine('+cast(X1 -0.5 as varchar)+','+cast(Y1 -0.03 as varchar)+','+cast(X1 +0.5 as    varchar)+','+cast(Y1 -0.03 as varchar)+ ')'+';'
+'$shape'+ cast(100+ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) as varchar)+'.Text =    "'+CONVERT(char(5), [Allocation Start Datetime], 108)+'"'+';'
+'$shape'+ cast(100+ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) as varchar)+'.TextStyle =   "Times"'+';'
+'$shape'+ cast(100+ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) as varchar)+'.LineStyle =     "Times"'+';'
+'$shape'+ cast(200+ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) as varchar)+' =    $page.DrawLine('+cast(X2 -0.1 as varchar)+','+cast(Y1 -0.03 as varchar)+','+cast(X2 +0.1 as    varchar)+','+cast(Y1 -0.03 as varchar)+ ')'+';'
+'$shape'+ cast(200+ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) as varchar)+'.Text =    "'+CONVERT(char(5), [Allocation End Datetime], 108)+'"'+';'
+'$shape'+ cast(200+ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) as varchar)+'.TextStyle =    "Times"'+';'
+'$shape'+ cast(200+ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) as varchar)+'.LineStyle =    "Times"'+';'


as output
FROM GanttReport(@from,@to,@TypeBigAC)
union all
select '$shape'+ cast(300+ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) as varchar)+' =     $page.DrawLine('+cast(X1 as varchar)+','+cast(Y2 as varchar)+','+cast(X2 as     varchar)+','+cast(Y1 as varchar)+ ')'
from GanttReportTowingLines(@from,@to,@TypeBigAC)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$commands = $SQLResult | foreach-object -process { $_.output }>> output.ps1
```

Answer (score 7):

You must set command type as stored procedure.

```
$SqlCmd.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::StoredProcedure
```

**UPDATE**

In your code `@from` and `@to` isn't parameters. Use code above to create SP with parameters.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE YQBreport1 @from datetime, @to datetime
AS 
declare  @TypeBigAC char(3)
''''
```

Comment: I add it and got error says, procedure YQBReport1 has no parameter and arguments were supplied...

Comment: I declared the type of from and to but not the value, for some reason system don't like me reply with too many '@', therefore I delete them in the code in front of parameter just for posting purpose:                                                            create PROCEDURE YQBreport1 
    AS 
    declare from datetime, to datetime, TypeBigAC char(3)
    select TypeBigAC='333'

Comment: sounds like the problem is that you didn't make from and to parameters.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan, please see my updated post, with the code, it was created as parameters

Comment: @Apriljuly You doesn't see any difference between yours and mine code? Look at closer.

Comment: sorry I over looked that T_T, it works! like a charm! Thank you!!!!@HamletHakobyan

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this:

```
sqlcmd -E -d Logging -S vansant.Server.local -Q "exec TestPass.ConsolidateMilestoneManualTestRuns @Milestone='$branch'"
```

Where @Milestone is a param.